# Django could not parse the remainder javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Im new to django so any help would be appreciated
im creating a django site but i cannot figure out how to redirect the url with javascript
im getting this error Could not parse the remainder:  '${id}' from '${id}'
my function:

```
<script>
function redir(id){
    window.location.href = "{% url 'detail' ${id} %}"
}
</script>
```

my site:

```
{% for item in store %}
    {% if item.available %}
        <div class="product-container" onclick="redir({{item.id}})">
            <img src="{{ item.imageURL }}" alt="Photo" onerror="this.src='http://via.placeholder.com/640x360'"/>
            <h1>{{ item.title }}</h1>
            <h4>RS.{{ item.price|floatformat:2 }}</h4>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you can only use the template tags "```{% url 'detail' %}```" inside the templates, it seems like you are using the url template tag inside an external js file..

Comment: actullay it is inside a script tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your variable's name is item:

```
<script>
function redir(id){
    window.location.href = "{% url 'detail' pk=item.id %}"
}
</script>
```

Comment: this worked what i did was replace the id with the url and entered the url fom the template